# Generic function with propertyname and value argument

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Is it possible to write a generic function with 2 arguments, where the first argument is propertyname, and second is the propertyvalue?

This (not working) typescript shows my intention:

```
declare function add<F extends Record<string, unknown>>(name: keyof F, value: T[path]): void;
add<{a: number; b: boolean}>('a', true); // Should be number
```

So when I call add with wrong value argument, I get type-error.

**Edit**
I realize that what i'm really after, is to type a function with overload signatures.

```
declare function add<F extends any>(obj: F, prop: keyof F, value: F[typeof prop]): void;
add({a: 1, b: false}, 'b', 42); // should give compiler error
```

Here it is the value argument, that the compiler infers as `number | boolean`, so it is satisfied by either. But aparently, there is no way to reflect the type depending on first argument.

Comment: Please provide an examples which should be without compiler error

Comment: The edit I posted, gives no compiler error, but I want it to infer that property name 'b' should be of type number. That is the essence.

Comment: Please let me know if my solution works for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've come up with a generic solution to my own question, that does not require a runtime function, to solve the problem.
It involves creating two utility-types: UnionToIntersection and FuncOverloads.
From the back, FuncOverloads generats a union type containing all the method signatures reflected from the type argument:

```
type FuncOverloads<T> = T extends Record<string, unknown>
? { [P in keyof T]: ((path: P, value: T[P]) => void) }[Exclude<keyof T, symbol>]
: never;
```

So it generates a type looking like this:

```
Type AddOverloads = FuncOverloads<{a: number; b: boolean}>; 
//   ((path: "a", value: number) => void) | ((path: "b", value: boolean) => void)
```

This function union type, then get specific, when put through the UnionToIntersection utility-type:

```
type UnionToIntersection<U> = 
      (U extends any ? (k: U) => void : never) extends ((k: infer I) => void) ? I : never;
```

So I end up with a overloaded function-signature:

```
declare const add: UnionToIntersection<FuncOverloads<{a: number; b: boolean}>>;
add('a', true); // Gives compiler error.
add('a', 42); // All fine
```

So as this [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAqgdgSwPZwCpIJJ2BATgZwgGNhk4AeGAPigF4oAoKKAChiggA8c4ATfKAEM4IKAH5WAawBcsAJR0aANyQJeUWXAhK8Crj36sWMqAjgAzPFAwLay1bwUSMGqFp24A3AwahIUADEAVzgiAHkPABskQX5yVBp6VA5uCD4BACViJFxecnxgXDMAcwAaKBDJOCQAdzgqJmZxKABvKABtAAVTOChJCBAkcyhUAF1ZFhYwQWAAC1lO8qVBSKCIWVQu0dt7NQUAX3aAUU4iVd4Icn7B4dRy-BAAWwAjJEiqUcbmTW08bwYLmdBLhoEQUAUhLxeLJ4GR0FgcARiKQUORgqEInhorF8OQWoJNEEXn8oM9ZK83hBhPsqFR-rFeCwAOSCJnlAAsACY5N4GczWeVCmseUA) shows, my asumptions about not being able to handle generic overloads was wrong:)

Answer (score 0):

You can curry your function:

```js
const add = <
    Key extends PropertyKey,
    Value,
    Obj extends Record<Key, Value>,
    Name extends keyof Obj
>(obj: Obj, name: Name, value: Obj[Name]):
    Obj[Name] => null as any

const result = add({ a: 42, b: true }, 'a', 42)

add({ a: 1, b: false }, 'b', 42); // error
```

*First part of the function:*

`Key` - infer object keys

`Value` - infer object values

`Obj` - infer whole object

`Name` - infer `name` argument

`Obj[Name]` - I'm not sure about `value` restriction.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FDDGHsDsGcBcAICGATZ8C88A8x5-gNICmAnvEQB6xGTLTwAKATuAA5FOwnEkA0u+AGqIANgFci-fPADyAIwBW5KjTrwASkQhNkWHr3jDxRAHxT8AOUQBbIsuq16Aa1LgAZrMXATACnCKALk8FA0gbIiCrWwMAN1EJIPkFAG0oogBdAEoAgTwk1PD0jBN4SDERESR6REgSEAgYBCYiaHKETBRkHwBvJCCAFgAmAzkg2CYJeABfAwByRFmDIcyQTp6++ABGEaC3UWg7GfhZuUX4ZYBueAB6a-ImFiYQIA)

[Here](https://catchts.com/infer-arguments), in my blog, you can find more about function argument inference

**UPDATE**

I thought you need to infer the `obj`.

Here you have an alternative version:

```js
type Obj = { a: number; b: boolean }

const add = <
    Name extends keyof Obj
>(name: Name, value: Obj[Name]):
    Obj[Name] => null as any

const result = add('a', 42)

add('b', 42); // error
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA8gRgKygXigbygQwFxQHYCuAtnBAE4DcUcucA9nQDYSZ5QC%20AUJwMZ14BnYFgAmIlFAA8nKLKgA5TEWgQAHsAh4RAqAGsIIOgDNYiTgD4AFHiURci5QBooAN0yMCd0wgDaDiAC6AJTYMnLwvv4BKOb4BIyMWDqsINx8gsJkEALxwqiYYpYA5JhFzgAsAExB3AUixXBlUFVBVAD0bVDkZHRk3EA)

Comment: I'm looking for a generic way to type the method-signature. I tried to edit question, to clarify, what im looking for.

Comment: @JesperJensen made an update

Comment: Your solution worked, but involves creating a runtime function, and I was out for a purly generic utility type. I posted a answer to my own question.

Comment: @JesperJensen I made an update. Just thought you want to infer `obj` argument.

Comment: I want to have a generic-type, that makes a function type with all the overloads, depending on the provided type-argument.